# merge cells with same values in microsoft office interop excel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, export-to-excel, excel-interop

i created a report which exports to excel. it exports just fine. what i want to do now is merge the consecutive cells in a column which have the same values. how do i do this? please help me.

this is code that generates the excel body:

```
Protected Sub generateExcelBody(ByVal xcelworksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet, ByVal recarray As Array, ByVal numofrecords As Integer)
    Dim chartrange As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
    chartrange = Nothing
    chartrange = xcelworksheet.Range("B5", "F5")
    chartrange.MergeCells = True
    chartrange.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft
    chartrange.VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter

    chartrange = Nothing
    chartrange = xcelworksheet.Range("A8", System.Reflection.Missing.Value)
    chartrange.FormulaR1C1 = "Record Series : " & hiddenrs.Value
    chartrange = Nothing
    chartrange = xcelworksheet.Range("A9", System.Reflection.Missing.Value)
    chartrange.FormulaR1C1 = "Department : " & hiddendept.Value
    chartrange = Nothing
    chartrange = xcelworksheet.Range("A10", System.Reflection.Missing.Value)
    chartrange.FormulaR1C1 = "Number of Records : " & numofrecords
    chartrange = Nothing
    chartrange = xcelworksheet.Range("A14", "F14")
    chartrange.Resize(numofrecords, 6).Value2 = recarray
    chartrange.Resize(numofrecords, 6).Borders(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft).Weight = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium
    chartrange.Resize(numofrecords, 6).Borders(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight).Weight = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium
    chartrange.Resize(numofrecords, 6).Borders(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin
    chartrange.Resize(numofrecords, 6).Borders(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlInsideVertical).Weight = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin
    chartrange.Resize(numofrecords, 6).Borders(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom).Weight = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium
    chartrange.Resize(numofrecords, 6).WrapText = True
    chartrange.Resize(numofrecords, 6).EntireRow.AutoFit()
    chartrange.Resize(numofrecords, 6).Font.Size = 10
    chartrange.Resize(numofrecords, 6).HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
    chartrange.Resize(numofrecords, 6).VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just received a notification that this question got 1000+ views so I thought I'd post what I did a year ago in solution to this problem. I hope you guys find it useful.

```
Public Sub mergeRows(ByVal grid As GridView)
    For rowIndex As Integer = (grid.Rows.Count - 2) To 0 Step -1
        Dim currRow As GridViewRow = grid.Rows(rowIndex)
        Dim prevRow As GridViewRow = grid.Rows(rowIndex + 1)

        For i As Integer = 0 To (currRow.Cells.Count - 1)
            If currRow.Cells(0).Text = prevRow.Cells(i).Text Then
                currRow.Cells(0).RowSpan = IIf(prevRow.Cells(0).RowSpan < 2, 2, prevRow.Cells(0).RowSpan + 1)
                prevRow.Cells(0).Visible = False
                If currRow.Cells(1).Text = prevRow.Cells(1).Text Then
                    currRow.Cells(1).RowSpan = IIf(prevRow.Cells(1).RowSpan < 2, 2, prevRow.Cells(1).RowSpan + 1)
                    prevRow.Cells(1).Visible = False
                    currRow.Cells(2).RowSpan = IIf(prevRow.Cells(1).RowSpan < 2, 2, prevRow.Cells(1).RowSpan + 1)
                    prevRow.Cells(2).Visible = False
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Protected Sub Gridview1_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Gridview1.PreRender
    mergeRows(Gridview1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is a if - else statement to check if the value of one column is duplicated or not. If yes -> merge the cells. You can either use built in merge cell function in Excel or "hide" the value of the duplicated cell + hide the border between the original and the duplicated cell. Found this while searching.

```
Sub FormatLikeDates() 
Dim d As Date, r As Long, n As Integer, c As Range 

For r = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
    If Int(Cells(r, 1)) = Int(Cells(r + 1, 1)) Then 
        n = n + 1 
    End If 
    If Int(Cells(r, 1)) <> Int(Cells(r + 1, 1)) And n > 0 Then 
        For Each c In Range(Cells(r - n + 1, 1), Cells(r, 1)) 
            c.Font.ColorIndex = 2 
            c.Interior.ColorIndex = 2 
        Next c 
        Range(Cells(r - n, 1), Cells(r, 1)).BorderAround ColorIndex:=3, Weight:=xlThin 
        n = 0 
    End If 
Next r
```

End Sub

Source : http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=57537